# Atmel Studio: Make project device serial-number agnostic

Tags: atmel, atmelstudio

My colleagues and I are using AtmelStudio v7.0.1645 to develop software for the Atmel SAM V71 Xplained Ultra (ATSAMV71Q21). We have a shared repository for code.

We have several of these boards and as a result we run into an issue when programming the board.

The `.cproj` file, under version control, has the serial number of the specific board placed in the **ToolNumber** field.

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
    ToolsVersion="14.0"> 
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <avrtool>com.atmel.avrdbg.tool.edbg</avrtool>
    <avrtoolserialnumber>ATML2000...</avrtoolserialnumber>
    <avrtoolinterface>SWD</avrtoolinterface>
    <com_atmel_avrdbg_tool_edbg>
      <ToolOptions>
        <InterfaceProperties>
          <SwdClock>2000000</SwdClock>
        </InterfaceProperties>
        <InterfaceName>SWD</InterfaceName>
      </ToolOptions>
      <ToolType>com.atmel.avrdbg.tool.edbg</ToolType>
      <ToolNumber>ATML2000...</ToolNumber>
      <ToolName>EDBG</ToolName>
    </com_atmel_avrdbg_tool_edbg>
    <avrtoolinterfaceclock>2000000</avrtoolinterfaceclock>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

At present if the field value is wrong then programming the board fails with the error: `[ERROR] The tool specified has been disconnected. Please reconnect the tool or choose another one`

The serial number should be user-specific, and should not be included in source control. How can Atmel Studio be made to work that way?

Answer (score 0):

May as well answer my own question...

I decided the solution was to use a few scripts, written using Python and Bash, to strip out the user-specific elements when committing; they are restored after the commit too.

Code is on GitHub: https://github.com/GRArmstrong/atmel-studio-git-hooks